# Linking Error in building Firebase powered app for iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ios8

We are using Firebase in an iOS app and just started to test it on iOS 8. When we try to compile the app in Xcode 6 against an iPhone 5S simulator, we got the following the error in linking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_fwrite$UNIX2003", referenced from:
leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::~PosixEnv() in Firebase(env_posix.o)
leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::~PosixEnv() in Firebase(env_posix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

We are doing in beta 3. Tried to clean everything and still have no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620375/cross-compile-libgcrypt-for-the-iphone-linker-error-cant-seem-to-find-fwri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an old SDK,

"We've pushed out a new version of the framework that addresses the _fwrite$UNIX2003 issue. Now, the code should compile with all the devices, and not just the 64-bit devices. Grab a new version on the downloads page!"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/m7vDEdF_lf4